# React Redux await until first action is complete

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I have an action that will take quite some time to complete. I want to inform the users that the action is currently taking place. To do this I am dispatching an action that updates a reducers state with a boolean.

The issue I am running into is that the larger action starts before the the state is updated. As a result, when a users clicks the generate button, they then experience the system lagging appose to UI informing them to wait.

How can I ensure the first action `startGeneration()` is completed before `buildKeyMap()` starts?  Same questioned for `reportProgress()`. I have redux-thunk installed.

```
export const generateKeyMap = (mapFrom, mapTo) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startGeneration()), // <-- this updates reducers state with a boolean, generatingMap: true
  dispatch(buildKeyMap(mapFrom, mapTo)) // <-- this takes a long time to finish
  };
};

export const buildKeyMap = (mapFrom, mapTo) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let keyMap = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < mapFrom.length; i++) {
      dispatch(reportProgress(i)); // <-- would like this to finish before moving on in the loop
      let randomIndex = randomIntFromInterval(0, mapTo.length - 1);
      let key = mapFrom[i].toString();
      let value = mapTo[randomIndex].toString();
      Object.assign(keyMap, { [key]: value });
      mapTo.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    }
    dispatch(stopGeneration()); // <--- Would like this to finish before delivering the map
    return { type: actionTypes.DELIVERKEYMAP, payload: keyMap };
  };
};

export const startGeneration = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.STARTKEYMAPGENERATION };
};
```

Comment: I sense there is something wrong with the implementation. Can you create a sandbox or post a whole code? Why are you building `keyMap` in an action?

Comment: I can't post all the code unfortunately. Each Action does indeed work no problem. The problem is that the first action will not complete until second is done. If I comment the second, the first works, vice versa. I put code in my actions and send the final product to my reducer. Where else would you put the logic? I have seen arguments about it being the reducer but I don't agree with this. I could build the logic elsewhere and send to product to the action but this still results in the same problem.

Comment: Try to use promises (async, await). You've just marked action creators as asynchronous, but did not do anything asynchronous. In the first snippet try to put await before first dispatch (and replace that `,` after dispatch for `;`) `await dispatch(startGeneration());`. Try to do the same in the second snippet, put await before those dispatches, but I think that there is more complicated situation.

Comment: I got the first one working so the user knows that things are in progress. I did this with a setTimeout function. However the second aync dispatch happens within a for loop. It appears that when the loop finishes then all the dispatches are fired in bulk. I want the dispatch to fire within each loop and update the store. I am dispatching the current progress for the user. How can I get through this single threading issue?